# Iceberg table does not see the generated Parquet file

Tags: java, time-series, apache-iceberg

In my use case, the table in Iceberg format is created. It only receives APPEND operations as it is about recording events in a time series stream. To evaluate the use of the **Iceberg format** in this use-case, I created a simple Java program that creates a set of 27600 lines. Both the metadata and the parquet file were created but I can't access them via the Java API (https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/java-api-quickstart/). I'm using `HadoopCatalog` and `FileAppender<GenericRecord>`. It is important to say that I can read the Parquet file created using `pyarrow` and `datafusion` modules via Python 3 script, and it is correct!

I believe that the execution of some method in my program that links the generated Parquet file to the table created in the catalog must be missing.

NOTE: I'm only using Apache Iceberg's Java API in version 1.0.0

There is an org.apache.iceberg.Transaction object in the API that accepts an org.apache.iceberg.DataFile but I haven't seen examples of how to use it and I don't know if it's useful to solve this problem either.

See the program below:

```java
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.iceberg.*;
import org.apache.iceberg.catalog.Catalog;
import org.apache.iceberg.catalog.TableIdentifier;
import org.apache.iceberg.data.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.iceberg.data.parquet.GenericParquetWriter;
import org.apache.iceberg.hadoop.HadoopCatalog;
import org.apache.iceberg.io.FileAppender;
import org.apache.iceberg.parquet.Parquet;
import org.apache.iceberg.relocated.com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import org.apache.iceberg.types.Types;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.List;

import static org.apache.iceberg.types.Types.NestedField.optional;
import static org.apache.iceberg.types.Types.NestedField.required;

public class IcebergTableAppend {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Appending records ");
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        String lakehouse = "/tmp/iceberg-test";
        conf.set(CatalogProperties.WAREHOUSE_LOCATION, lakehouse);
        Schema schema = new Schema(
                required(1, "hotel_id", Types.LongType.get()),
                optional(2, "hotel_name", Types.StringType.get()),
                required(3, "customer_id", Types.LongType.get()),
                required(4, "arrival_date", Types.DateType.get()),
                required(5, "departure_date", Types.DateType.get()),
                required(6, "value", Types.DoubleType.get())
        );
        PartitionSpec spec = PartitionSpec.builderFor(schema)
                .month("arrival_date")
                .build();
        TableIdentifier id = TableIdentifier.parse("bookings.rome_hotels");
        String warehousePath = "file://" + lakehouse;
        Catalog catalog = new HadoopCatalog(conf, warehousePath);
        // rm -rf  /tmp/iceberg-test/bookings
        Table table = catalog.createTable(id, schema, spec);
        List<GenericRecord> records = Lists.newArrayList();
        // generating a bunch of records
        for (int j = 1; j <= 12; j++) {
            int NUM_ROWS_PER_MONTH = 2300;
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS_PER_MONTH; i++) {
                GenericRecord rec = GenericRecord.create(schema);
                rec.setField("hotel_id", (long) (i * 2) + 10000);
                rec.setField("hotel_name", "hotel_name-" + i + 1000);
                rec.setField("customer_id", (long) (i * 2) + 20000);
                rec.setField("arrival_date",
                        LocalDate.of(2022, j, (i % 23) + 1)
                                .plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
                rec.setField("departure_date",
                        LocalDate.of(2022, j, (i % 23) + 5));
                rec.setField("value", (double) i * 4.13);
                records.add(rec);
            }
        }
        File parquetFile = new File(
                lakehouse + "/bookings/rome_hotels/arq_001.parquet");
        FileAppender<GenericRecord> appender = null;
        try {
            appender = Parquet.write(Files.localOutput(parquetFile))
                    .schema(table.schema())
                    .createWriterFunc(GenericParquetWriter::buildWriter)
                    .build();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        try {
            appender.addAll(records);
        } finally {
            try {
                appender.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found out how to fix the Java program.

Just add the lines below to the end of the `main` method

```java
PartitionKey partitionKey = new PartitionKey(table.spec(), table.schema());
DataFile dataFile = DataFiles.builder(table.spec())
        .withPartition(partitionKey)
        .withInputFile(localInput(parquetFile))
        .withMetrics(appender.metrics())
        .withFormat(FileFormat.PARQUET)
        .build();
 Transaction t = table.newTransaction();
 t.newAppend().appendFile(dataFile).commit();
 // commit all changes to the table
 t.commitTransaction();
```

Also add to your POM file the dependency below

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

This avoids the runtime error shown below:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat`

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right track.  I was using Parquet.write(table.io().newOutputFile(location))... Threw me off that it says on writing files using Table.io() - the java doc says "/** Returns a {@link FileIO} to read and write table data and metadata files. */". Which is false, doesn't do anything w/ metadata files!